# PHP Do While Sending Emails

Tags: php, email, loops, pear, do-while

I have the following code, which sends emails but it is embedding one email in another instead of sending them separately, the output is also below.

Any thoughts?

H.

**Email output**

```
SMTP Test Email Message

Dear Gary,

Dear Jaime,

Test Message

Here is a quick email test to see what it comes through like. Link: = 

Test

Does it do formatting correctly and what is the situation with dual = names appearing etc?

Kind regards,

Gary. 
 Link: http:// 

Test

Does it do formatting correctly and what is the situation with dual names appearing etc?

Kind regards,

Gary.
```

**Code snippet**

```
do {
    $dear = "<font face='Arial' size='2'>Dear " . $row["forename"] . ",<br><br></font>";

    $email_body = $dear . "<font face='Arial' size='2'>" . stripslashes($body) . "</font><br><br><font face='Arial' size='2'>" . $linky . "  <a href='" . $row["link"] . "'> " . $row["link"] . "</a> </font> <br><br><font face='Arial' size='2'>" . stripslashes($body2) . "</font>";

    $subject = $sub;

$bcc = "blob.blob@blob.co.uk";
$recipients = $row["email"].",".$bcc;
// Constructing the email
$sender = $bcc;                                             
$recipient = $recipients;                               
$subject = $subject;                                                

$html = $email_body;      
$crlf = "\n";
    $headers = array(
        'To'        => $row["Mail"],
        'From'          => $sender,
        'Return-Path'   => $sender,
        'Subject'       => $subject
                     );

// Creating the Mime message
$mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);

// Setting the body of the email
//$mime->setTXTBody($text);
    $mime->setHTMLBody($html);


// Set body and headers ready for base mail class
$body = $mime->get();
$headers = $mime->headers($headers);

// SMTP authentication params
$smtp_params["host"]     = "scr.emserv.com";
$smtp_params["port"]     = "25";
$smtp_params["auth"]     = true;
$smtp_params["username"] = "blob.blob@blob.co.uk";
$smtp_params["password"] = "blob";

// Sending the email using smtp
$mail =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtp_params);
sleep(2);
$result = $mail->send($recipient, $headers, $body);

for($i=0;$i<$elements1;$i++){
$bar1->increase(); //calls the bar with every processed element
$bar1->setMessage('Sending emails (2 second delay between each): '.(($i+1)*$sent).'%');

}

if($row["sent"]=='YES'){
$reminder = $row["reminder"] + 1;
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET reminder = $reminder WHERE respondent_id = " . $row["respondent_id"] . " ") or die("Could not update record<br>".mysql_error());
}else

$update = mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET sent = 'YES' WHERE respondent_id = " . $row["respondent_id"] . " ") or die("Could not update record<br>".mysql_error());

} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results));
    $bar1->setMessage('Emails have now been sent: 100%');
    }
```

Comment: Debug by dumping out the stuff you're passing into the `$mail->send()` call - if the doubled emails are in there, then it's your code causing the problem. And at the end, if the mail doesn't sent, you still update the DB to say it HAS been sent!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this issue is that you're not clearing the $body variable. Every time through the loop it is basically appending it to the $email_body variable in this line:

`$email_body = $dear . "<font face='Arial' size='2'>" . stripslashes($body) ...`

Farther down you set $body to the entire message:

`$body = $mime->get();`

[get() returns the entire message as a string](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.get.php). It also doesn't make sense that you would be utilizing $body originally since it's not initialized in this do while loop until after the first line I listed.